# How to count elements grouped by an specific field?

Tags: views

I have a view with elements grouped by some categories, I would like to add the number of elements grouped in the same category, something like this:

### Categ A (2)

- element
- element

### Categ B (3)

- element
- element
- element

I tried with aggregations but I didn't get the result I was looking for. Is there any way to resolver this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Aggregator Plus](https://drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) for this.